# Returning wrong type, how to fix?

Tags: python, data-science

I have a question that I got wrong as I have the wrong type given in my code.

The outline of the question:

[image]

The first question I tried to answer is written here:

**Which two sectors are most often confused with each other and how many times?**

0) Consumer Discretionary
    1) Consumer Staples
    2) Energy
    3) Financials
    4) Health Care
    5) Industrials
    6) Information Technology
    7) Materials
    8) Real Estate
    9) Telecommunication Services
    10) Utilities

My code that I tried is this:

```py
def question_1():
    ans1 = np.array([5, 7])
    num_scen1 = 5
    return ans1, num_scen1
```

The assertment statement below my code looks like this:

```
ans1, num_scen1 = question_1()
assert type(ans1) == list, "Incorrect type"
assert type(ans1[0]) == tuple, "Incorrect type"
assert type(ans1[0][0]) == int, "Incorrect type"
assert type(num_scen1) == int, "Incorrect type"
```

My code triggered this error:

[image]

How can I help fix my code to pass the assertion statement by having the right type?

Comment: In `ans1 = np.array([5, 7])`, `ans` is of type `np.ndarray`, not `list`. The assignment also talks specifically about lists, not `ndarray`s, so I'm not sure why you used one here anyway.

Comment: If I remove the  np.array, and have it as ans1 = ([5, 7])

it triggers the assert statement #3, which is  == tuple, "Incorrect type".

Comment: Well, as you can see, `ans` should be a list of tuples that contain integers. If in your code `ans` is _not_ a list of tuples that contain integers (like `ans = [(0, 1), (2, 3)]`), the checks won't pass

Comment: I believe I just got it correct by changing it to: ans1 = [(5, 7)] . Thank you for helping with this. I would upvote your comment but I don't seem to have that ability just yet

Comment: However, I would just point out that the question contradicts the example given. The question says the ans should be a list containing a -single- tuple. The example code gives a list containing two tuples.

Answer (score 0):

1. function `question_1()` returns 1st element as a type of `numpy array` not a `list` so we should match it with `np.ndarray`.
2. Since here we are checking `type` of variables, we might prefer `isinstance()` method, so update the code like below:

   ```
   ans1, num_scen1 = question_1()
   assert isinstance(ans1, np.ndarray), "Incorrect Type"
   assert isinstance(ans1[0], tuple), "Incorrect type"
   assert isinstance(ans1[0][0], int), "Incorrect type"
   assert isinstance(num_scen1, int), "Incorrect type"
   ```